# Что значит "Реализуйте логическую арифметику, при которой в одном слове хранилось бы 16 логических переменных"?

Tags: ассемблер

Я не понимаю условие данной задачи. Можете мне объяснить, что я должен сделать? Код на ассемблере мне не нужен. Перефразируйте для меня задачу попроще, пожалуйста.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что "это вам к автору задачи"

Answer (score 2):

Под "словом", вероятно, имеется ввиду тип Word (16bit). Итого вам надо реализовать логическую арифметику по хранению 16 булевых значений в одной 16-битной переменной.

А вот какой именно объем логической арифметики реализовать, и как - это вам к автору задачи.

Comment: Простите, но я всё равно не понимаю, что от меня хотят в этой задаче. Типа получать результат посредством логических операций и заносить каждый результат в свой бит?

Comment: @ArtemSmirnov "это вам к автору задачи"